# equilibrium solutions question? with initial value and limit question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=y(y-2)(y-3)^2$
if $y(0) = 1$ what is the limits of $y(x)$ as $x \to +/-\infty?$
I have found the solutions of the differential equation and sketched the direction field if thats to any help on this one? $0$=stable $2$=unstable $3$=semi-stable :) any solutions/tips? :D

Comment: Consider that, in the region $ \ 0 \ < \ y \ < 2 \ , $ the sign of $ \ y' \ $ is $ \ + \cdot - \cdot \ - \ = \ + \ . $  So with $ \ y' > 0 \  $ starting out at $ \ y(0) = 1 \ , $ which equilibrium value will $ \ y(t) \ $ tend to "after a long time" ( $ \ t \rightarrow + \infty \ $ )?  If we project into the past ( $ \ t \rightarrow - \infty \ $ ) , what equilibrium value is the function approaching (or, for time running "forward", what equilibrium value is $ \ y \ $ "running away from")?

Comment: well idk, I messed up.. its (y-3)^2 and idk where you got + * - * - from? :O

Comment: If you put $ \ y = 1 \ $ into your differential equation (or any value in the interval $ \ 0 < y < 2 \ $ ), the first factor $ \ y \ $ is positive, the second factor, $ \ (y - 2) \ , $ is negative, and the third factor, $ \ (y-3)^2 , $ is now positive.  So the product is a negative number, making $ \ y' < 0 \ . $  That now changes the direction of the flow of $ \ y \ $ from what I had earlier.

Comment: well if I substitute y=1 into y' then I get -4 (by using calculator) so y' < 0 idd, but idk how this helps me solve this question? :P I guess its running away from 2 and approaching 0 or something? as t increases? idk man -.-

Comment: The sign of $ \ y' \ $ is all we care about for this question. You can find the sign of $ \ y' \ $ in each of the intervals that the equilibrium values of $ \ y \ $ separate:  $ \ y < 0 \ , \ 0 < y < 2 \ , \ 2 < y < 3 \ , \ \text{and} \ y > 3 \ $ .  The signs tell you which way the "flow" runs in each interval, and thereby, what type of equilibrium you have at $ \ y = 0 \ , \ 2 \ , \ \text{and} \ 3 \ . $

Comment: As for your conclusion about the flow, that's correct.

Comment: oh yeah when I mean its stable then I mean on both sides of the line y=0 are approaching it, and with unstable, both sides are running away, semi 1 approaching 1running away.. but how do I find the limit I mean the signs for each interval I already knew when I posted this question.. :P

Comment: Yes, that's right.  In this flow field, it turns out you have one equilibrium of each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find three equilibrium points as:

$$y = 0, 2, 3$$

A direction field plot, with the initial condition (green) shows:

[image]

We can numerically solve this ODE and here is a plot of those results (note what happens to the limit of $y(t)$ as we approach $\pm~ \infty$). Compare this to the direction field plot and make the connection:

[image]

Another approach is to just draw the phase line.

Comment: well yeah, and how exactly do I use this to find the limit? thats the real question XD

Comment: In the interval $ \ 0 <  y < 2 \ , $ all curves flow away from $ \ y = 2 \ $ and toward $ \ y = 0 \ . $  So $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} \ y(x) = 2 \ $ and $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \ y(x) = 0 \ . $

Comment: OH yeah, now it makes sense, thanks man :)